# Why am I getting a strange error : nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, api, swiftui

Disclaimer: I am new to Swift and IOS in general, so please keep that in mind!

While attempting to connect to an API, I am receiving the following error:
`nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed`.

Please find below the code used:

```
@State public var data = PoemData(title: String("Poem Name"), content: String("Poem Content"), poetData: PoetData(name: "Poet Name"))
    
    func getData() {
        let urlstring = "https://www.poemist.com/api/v1/randompoems"
        let url = URL(string: urlstring)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {data, _, error in
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(PoemData.self, from: data)
                        self.data = decodedData
                        
                    } catch {
                        print ("Error! Something went wrong, yikes")
                        
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

And the data model:

```
import Foundation

struct PoemData: Decodable {
    public var title: String
    public var content: String
    public var poetData: PoetData
    
}

struct PoetData: Decodable {
    var name: String
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is purely a Simulator message. It won't happen on a device, and it doesn't affect the behavior of your app, so just ignore it.

Comment: That's correct. I tested it on my device and everything seems to be working fine. Thanks a lot!